# Ruby hash.dig using array as argument?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, splat

I have a nested hash of data

```
foo => {
  'user' => { 
    'address' => {
      'street' => '1234'
    }
  }
}
```

I can access the values using Hash.dig

```
foo.dig('user', 'address', 'street')
1234
```

How would you use hash.dig when the values are variable, and are defined in an array?

```
query=["users", "address", "street"]
  
foo.dig(query) # <= doesn't work  
foo.dig(query.to_s) # <= doesn't work
```

Looking at the ruby docs, Hash.dig appears to take multiple parameters, but does not take an array

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

Comment: Keep in mind that an array is a valid Hash key so calling `Hash#dig` with an array argument is valid and sensible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it with a splat operator to split up an array into an argument list in such a way:

```rb
foo.dig(*query)
```

Comment: The name is "splat operator", btw

Answer (score 2):

I would use Alex's answer for a typical use-case but since it splats out the array into arguments, there is more overhead and with large inputs, I get a stack too deep error. This isn't an error you will face unless you have a huge list but maybe worth understanding anyway.

```
# one million keys
# note that none of these are actually present in the hash
query = 1.upto(1_000_000).to_a

foo.dig(*query)
# => StackTooDeep

query.reduce(foo) do |memo, key|
  memo&.dig(key) || break
end
# => returns nil instantly
```

Comment: If you have a structure a million levels deep you've likely got other problems.

Comment: Yeah agreed but I think the lesson here is not so much About dig but rather that splatting arrays into args doesn't work with big arrays.

Comment: @maxpleaner Thank you for the answer! It made me think of other uses of `reduce` paradigm, beyond the use discussed in this post (to work around "splat" for big arrays). And no, I did not take this toy example as advice to create monsters that are a million levels deep. On the contrary! I simply suspect that one of these days, I might have to debug the code where someone had *accidentally* created such a Thing. Maybe even a few Things, if they knew about loops. :)

Comment: Hah, that's good to hear. Yeah I feel like getting better at enumerable methods has been the number one way my code's improved over the last few years.